# Is the voltage across a diode always 0.7 volt?

Tags: diodes, analog

The question comes because I read that "for actual practical diode, when Id = 0 A, Vd = 0v". Fine, that's because no current flows through it. But shouldn't at that instant the circuit be open? Since no current flows through the diode?

A picture would make things clearer:
[image]

Why won't VD1 be a open circuit? Since we need at least 0.7 V of flowing current? Why would VD1 be 0?

Comment: The rightmost diode is an open circuit, so no current flows through either diode. With \$I_{D1} = 0\$ you must have \$V_{D1} = 0\$.

Comment: If there's zero current thru a dead short it doesn't mean it's open circuit.

Comment: In general there is an exponential relation between the diode voltage and current.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Shockley_diode_equation

Comment: If a resistor has zero volts across it, and no current flows, what is its resistance?

Answer (score 13):

> Is the voltage across a diode always 0.7 volt?

No, the relationship between voltage and current for a diode is typically approximated by the [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Shockley_diode_equation):

$$I=I_\mathrm{S} \left( e^{V_\mathrm{D}/(n V_\mathrm{T})}-1 \right)$$

Where *V*<sub>D</sub> is the voltage across the diode  *V*<sub>T</sub> is the "thermal voltage" (a temperature dependent physical constant, about 26 millivolts at room temperature). *I*<sub>S</sub> is the reverse saturation current of the diode and *n* is a constant called the *ideality factor* (which varies between different types of diodes, and is typically between 1 and 2)

When there is no current through a diode there is also no voltage across it.

Technically with two diodes in inverse series there will be a very small current flow since diodes do have some reverse leakage. In turn this means there will be a very small voltage across the forward biased diode. In practice however this current and voltage will typically be negligible and would be ignored during circuit analysis.

If we want to put actual numbers on this then we can do a simple analysis. Lets assume the two diodes are the same and the voltage across the pair of diodes is significantly larger than the thermal voltage. The current through a reverse-biased diode is approximately \$Is\$, so the current through the forward biased diode will also be approximately \$Is\$. This means for the forward biased diode.

$$I_\mathrm{S} \approx I_\mathrm{S} \left( e^{V_\mathrm{D}/(n V_\mathrm{T})}-1 \right)$$

$$1 \approx e^{V_\mathrm{D}/(n V_\mathrm{T})}-1$$

$$2 \approx e^{V_\mathrm{D}/(n V_\mathrm{T})}$$

$$0.69 \approx V_\mathrm{D}/(n V_\mathrm{T})$$

$$0.69n V_\mathrm{T} \approx V_\mathrm{D}$$

Comment: I think you mean "inverse series" for that last paragraph?

Comment: Yeah, someone proposed an edit fixing that which I accepted.

Comment: Also, the value 0.7 volts also depends on the type of semiconductor used (GaAs diodes, for example, have a drop of 1.2 volts), and is also different for diodes not based on a pn-junction (like Schottky diodes).

Comment: Nice answer, but "...temperature dependent physical constant..." is a bit of an oxymoron. Is there a form using \$ k_B T\$?

Comment: You can find the definition of the thermal voltage at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant#Role_in_semiconductor_physics:_the_thermal_voltage

Comment: @Peter there is always a built in potential inside the diode which is called the depletion region.

Answer (score 7):

Peter Green's answer is a good one.  Let me approach the other part of your question from a different angle:

Consider this simple circuit with resistors and no diodes.  It is an open circuit, so no current can flow. Let's ignore real-life complications such as parasitic capacitances, etc.

[image]

1. Initially, the voltage on both sides of the resistor is 0V.
2. When SW1 closes, the voltage on the left of the resistor is 1V, and the voltage on the right is still 0V.  *This is only true for an instant!*
3. Here's the trick! The voltage difference across the resistor causes current to flow through the resistor. Since there is not a complete current path, it only takes a tiny amount of electrons to migrate through the resistor until both sides are at the same potential.

Now you have a steady-state situation where there is 1V on the left side of the resistor and 1V on the right side.  The voltage difference across the resistor is zero and there is no current flow.

The resistor will continue to have 0V across it until you hook up a load, which allows current to flow, which causes a voltage differential across the resistor.

To relate this to your diode circuit: remember that there is a small reverse leakage current through real diodes.  This current is sufficient to equalize voltage on each side of the diode, as long as there is no path for the current to continue flowing.